# rotate uncompressed bmp by a multiple of 90

Tags: c, bmp, image-rotation

I need to rotate a bmp given an angle in multiples of 90. Im trying to figure out how to accomplish this. Can somebody guide me in the right direction to approach this problem?

The rotation angles, which are multiples of 90 could be positive as well as negative. It should also accept angle 0

thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: do you have it unpacked from the file in a matrix?

Comment: yeah, the pixels are stored in 2-d arary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better approach:

```
struct bitmap
{
  int** array[3]; //RGB
  int N;
  int M;
};

void f(struct bitmap source, struct bitmap dest)
{ for(int i=0;i<source.N;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<source.M;j++)
    {
      dest.array[j][source.N-i-1]=source.array[i][j];
    }
  }
  dest.N=array.M;
  dest.M=array.N;
}
```

Here's a picture
[image]

to rotate anti-clockwise you change only

```
dest.result[source.M-j-1][i]=source.array[i][j];
```

Comment: it could be positive multiples of 90 or negative multiples of 90. The pixels are stored in a pointer, but its represented as a 2-d array.

Comment: Okay im going to give this a try. Although how do i include the option to rotate the image by multiples of +||- 90?

Comment: i'll let you figure it out for the case when it 180

Comment: modified to struct because **array, N, M should always go together

Comment: Can your get full sample?